# how to fix an issue with custom subclass of uitableviewcell reuse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Before I get crucified for this, let me state... Yes, I have read every "relevant" answer on this topic and have not found a workable solution. Most "correct" answers are pre-ARC and discuss "releasing" a cell, which just isn't done anymore. Secondly, my problem is not "global", meaning some views have no problems, while others do. So here is my question...

I have sub-classed uitableviewcell and setup some uilabels & custom uiviews. From there I wired everything up in ib (Xcode 5.x iOS 7.x). Once I put in the appropriate code and create the tableview & dynamic cells from a nsarray "not mutable" everything works exactly as expected with no issues.

This is the fun part. I am making changes to allow the data source of the tableview, which is an nsarray to be mutable to allow adding and removing of items / cells. This is where things get hairy. When I start to add more objects to the array and when the reuse cell is being put on screen visual data from old cells is being reused on new cells. I say "visual" because once the cell is selected the view updates to display the correct information. The part that is interesting is that as I stated I have some uilabels which never have any problems being redisplayed, my custom views however are now the piece of the puzzle that is displaying info from past cells, and when scrolling back up, the original cells no longer display the correct information. Once the cell is tapped, then the cell updates and displays the correct information.

the most confusing bit of this is that before my array was mutable and had a static amount of objects this worked fine. Even if a cell went off screen and came back, it was still the correct information being displayed. Now I know that shouldn't have anything to do with it, but it is strange that it worked using the same tableview & cell code that I am using now.

I have tried adding in

```
MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (!cell) {
     cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"]; // note: obviously as stated, tacking on "autorelease" here as mention in other suggestions is not going to work.
}
```

Which doesn't fix the issue.

I tried overriding the "prepareForReuse" method on my custom cell subclass and that does not resolve the issue either. I have made the views, "strong" & "weak", and all that and still every 3rd or so cell gets repeated with garbage data until it is refreshed. Again, the uilabels which are setup the same way as the views have no problems and data is never reused. I would say there is a problem with my custom views, but setting up the table from a static source of identical information there is no problem.

I would like to post some code, but it's all pretty generic code for tableviews & delegates. any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

As i said the code is all pretty generic, but apparently it needs posing anyway so here it is..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MyThing *thing = self.stuffArray[indexPath.row];

    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.thisLabel.text = thing.someText;
    cell.thatLabel.text = thing.otherText;

    cell.view1.someProptery = thing.object1.property
    cell.view2.someProptery = thing.object2.property
    cell.view3.someProptery = thing.object3.property 
    //"someProperty" on "view..." is an NSInt that is used to determine custom drawing in the view.

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: First, you have your issues hidden within a wall of text larger than the wall of China. Make it more clear about what the issues are. Second, the problem with your UILabel's displaying the incorrect information is inside your `cellForRow` or `willDisplayCell` methods. What happens is the reuse Cell literally reuses the cells that are popped off when you scroll. That means that when they are used again, it has all the information in it still. So you need to make sure you reset EVERY possibly UILabel when you're setting the cell properties

Comment: Provide your complete `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: @LyricalPanda if you would have bothered to read the question you would, 1) realize the reason for the lengthy explanation, 2) understand that i am not having issues with ANY UILabels. please read the question, then post something constructive.

Comment: Did you override the synthesized setter for someProperty on your custom views?  If so, can you post that?  (my theory is that (a) you should have, and (b) that setter must call [self setNeedsDisplay])

Comment: @danh No, because there was no need. It is not doing anything special with it other than just referencing the passed in value. The VC tells the view to call setNeedsDisplay. I will try adding that in my cell method for each cell and see what happens. Nice idea.

Comment: @DoS I think that's the key.  The setter is changing the view state without telling the view that it needs to be redrawn.  Please see my answer.

Comment: Are you sure that in cellForRowAtIndexPath method you don't have any 'if' statement?

Comment: @arturdev positive. check the accepted answer for the solution.

Comment: @DoS 1) We'll agree to disagree on this one. 2) My comment was actually close to the accepted answer where you need to reset the property for the cells being reused. Just because it was a property on a UIView instead of a UILabel doesn't mean it wasn't constructive. I'll admit I got lost in the word vomit, but that doesn't excuse you from totally dismissing my constructive explanation as to what was happening.

Comment: @LyricalPanda my "word vomit" was a DETAILED explanation to weed out any incorrect, unrelated or already attempted suggestions offered from those skimming the question and not fully understanding the problem. unfortunately your comment did not really have any relevance to the actual solution, but appreciate your input. on a side note, my dismissal stemmed from your "constructive explanation" being incorrect, along with your initial negative remark about posting to much info. there is nothing wrong with being thorough, and have no doubt if i would have caught flack from posting too little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key to the solution lies in your comment about the custom views in the cells.  If cellForRowAtIndexPath is altering the states of those views, they need to know that they must be redrawn, so you'll need to augment the synthesized setter in your custom view.m that has someProperty.

If the someProperty determines how this view get's drawn, then it's incumbent upon the setter to indicate that the view is out of date....

```
- (void)setSomeProperty:(NSInteger)someInt {
    _someProperty = someInt;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: so i went ahead and added in a call to setNeedsDisplay in the cell reuse method, which worked. i will try just adding that to the setting method and see how that works.

Comment: Makes sense that it works.  I think setNeedsDisplay is better done here.  That way, no matter what context the change to someProperty takes place (eg. a different superview than the table cell), the view will behave correctly.  (and you won't have to yuck up your table view code with work that's private to this view).

Comment: absolutely, and worked like a champ. great catch, and now i can take out my other setNeedsDisplay calls, from my other update methods.

Comment: Actually if you're using solution like this, then this means that you have done something bad in your logic.
When you do everything right, then its enough just to [call self.tableView reloadData];
So, I'm pretty sure that still you have that problem, and this way you just workaround it.

Comment: Sorry @arturdev, but you are incorrect.  There was a bug in the OP's custom UIView that kept it from updating when it's view was out of date (out of date because someProperty changes how it looks).  The correct fix to that bug is setNeedsDisplay.  There's no possibility to (and no need to) fix with reloadData.  The bug would appear in any superview that contains that custom view, not just a table view.

Comment: danh is absolutely correct. i was calling "setNeedsDisplay" on the view from the view controller, anytime a change was made. by adding it into a custom method in the view, the view is responsible for updating itself, vs. always having the view constantly needing to be refreshed. this would be like setting the text on a label and the text color to red, but always having to reset the color back to red anytime it went off view, and came back on screen. this obviously isn't how a label works, and now the custom view functions the same way.

Comment: Calling `setNeedsDisplay` is best practice when you do something in your custom view in `- drawRect:` method.